# Is there any credibility to the "details" in Supernatural?

Tags: plot-explanation, supernatural

I have watched 6 seasons of [Supernatural](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460681/), and in almost every one of them, Sam and Dean talks about many different kinds of monsters- with different names, killing-methods and habits.

So I was wondering, is there any credibility to that information? I mean, monsters are not considered real by most people (and most probably they aren't), but I do know there are many myths and legends about them- originating from ancient times. For example, in Supernatural, they almost always use salt to keep monsters away, and also the much-used Devil's Trap.

So is this kind of lore real or just made up for the movie?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Supernatural is inspired from several folk lore, legends, myths and a creative team. So most of it is born out of the existing myths out there. Of course, the team goes on to make some stuff of their own. The thing is, Supernatural borrows from myths all over the world. The salt thing and devil's trap are myths that exist. Though I wouldn't worry about the series being *credible* because they often involve plots that throw you off your screen like the Horsemen, heaven, hell etc etc. Just enjoy the show! :)

Comment: Glad to know at least some of it is _real_. :) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Roshnal for more details on many myths, legends etc you might like to check out _Supernatural: John Winchester's Journal_ (2009), by [Alexander C. Irvine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_C._Irvine) who basically made this text "as if" the original Winchester's father's Hunter Journal. Anothe book by the same author and sounds good, but this one I didn't read is _The Supernatural Book of Monsters, Spirits, Demons, and Ghouls_ (2007).

Comment: Also "The Mythology of Supernatural: The Signs and Symbols Behind the Popular TV Series" by Nathan Robert Brown provides quite a lot of in-depth information on the origins of things seen in the show. It can be a little dry at times but pretty fascinating